# sql ORDER BY multiple values in specific order?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

Ok I have a table with a indexed key and a non indexed field. 
I need to find all records with a certain value and return the row.
I would like to know if I can order by multiple values.

Example:

```
id     x_field
--     -----
123    a
124    a
125    a
126    b
127    f
128    b
129    a
130    x
131    x
132    b
133    p
134    p
135    i
```

pseudo: would like the results to be ordered like this, `where ORDER BY x_field = 'f', 'p', 'i', 'a'`

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE id NOT IN (126)
ORDER BY x_field 'f', 'p', 'i', 'a'
```

So the results would be:

```
id     x_field
--     -----
127    f
133    p
134    p
135    i
123    a
124    a
125    a
129    a
```

The syntax is valid but when I execute the query it never returns any results, even if I limit it to 1 record. Is there another way to go about this?

Think of the x_field as test results and I need to validate all the records that fall in the condition. I wanted to order the test results by failed values, passed values. So I could validate the failed values first and then the passed values using the ORDER BY.

What I can't do:

- GROUP BY, as I need to return the specific record values
- WHERE x_field IN('f', 'p', 'i', 'a'), I need all the values as I'm trying to use one query for several validation tests. And x_field values are not in DESC/ASC order

After writing this question I'm starting to think that I need to rethink this, LOL!

Comment: Maybe a union instead? Construct separate queries in the order you want results returned in, then do a union of those queries?

Answer (score 262, accepted):

```
...
WHERE
   x_field IN ('f', 'p', 'i', 'a') ...
ORDER BY
   CASE x_field
      WHEN 'f' THEN 1
      WHEN 'p' THEN 2
      WHEN 'i' THEN 3
      WHEN 'a' THEN 4
      ELSE 5 -- fallback for values not inside the IN clause. eg : x_field = 'b'
   END, id
```

Answer (score 43):

Try:

```
ORDER BY x_field='f', x_field='p', x_field='i', x_field='a'
```

You were on the right track, but by putting **x_field** only on the **'f'** value, the other three were treated as constants and not compared against anything in the dataset.

Comment: Does Postgres support implicit boolean? If so, how does boolean sort?

Comment: I liked this solution but it didn't return anything again.

Comment: @gbn, Yes and false<true. I would have expected this to work.

Comment: Yes, it works event in Postgres. Note to this solution is that you get result sorted in reverse order. So you have to put fields in reverse order: ORDER BY  x_field='A', x_field='I', x_field='P', x_field='F',

Comment: To reverse and get the correct order you can also add the (!=) operator:

    ORDER BY x_field!='f', x_field!='p', x_field!='i', x_field!='a'

Answer (score 40):

I found a much cleaner solution for this:

```
ORDER BY array_position(ARRAY['f', 'p', 'i', 'a']::varchar[], x_field)
```

Note: array_position needs Postgres v9.5 or higher.

Comment: thanks, much preferred this to the CASE methods. Works with integers too; `array_position(ARRAY[1, 0]::integer[], x_field)`

Comment: Liked this solution as its simple to use, especially if the count of values is less.

Comment: Is this inefficient, though?

Answer (score 35):

You can use a LEFT JOIN with a "VALUES ('f',1),('p',2),('a',3),('i',4)" and use the second column in your order-by expression. Postgres will use a Hash Join which will be much faster than a huge CASE if you have a lot of values. And it is easier to autogenerate.

If this ordering information is fixed, then it should have its own table.

Comment: This is by far the most elegant solution!

Comment: If someone needs a complete query that uses proposed approach, I added it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65317490/12833205).

Answer (score 21):

Use a `case` switch to translate the codes into numbers that can be sorted:

```
ORDER BY
  case x_field
  when 'f' then 1
  when 'p' then 2
  when 'i' then 3
  when 'a' then 4
  else 5
  end
```

Answer (score 7):

The `CASE` and `ORDER BY` suggestions should all work, but I'm going to suggest a horse of a different color. Assuming that there are only a reasonable number of values for `x_field` and you already know what they are, create an [enumerated type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-enum.html) with F, P, A, and I as the values (plus whatever other possible values apply). Enums will sort in the order implied by their `CREATE` statement. Also, you can use meaninful value names—your real application probably does and you have just masked them for confidentiality—without wasted space, since only the ordinal position is stored.

Answer (score 4):

For someone who is new to **ORDER BY** with **CASE** this may be useful

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN GRADE = 'A' THEN 0
         WHEN GRADE = 'B' THEN 1
         ELSE 2 END
```

Answer (score 4):

@bobflux's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6341581/12833205) is great. I would like to extend it by adding a complete query that uses proposed approach.

```
select tt.id, tt.x_field
from target_table as tt
-- Here we join our target_table with order_table to specify custom ordering.
left join
    (values ('f', 1), ('p', 2), ('i', 3), ('a', 4)) as order_table (x_field, order_num)
    on order_table.x_field = tt.x_field
order by
    order_table.order_num, -- Here we order values by our custom order.
    tt.x_field;            -- Other values can be ordered alphabetically, for example.
```

Here is complete [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cgdBko5AkuX55D8iVqghMT/1).

Answer (score 1):

Since i don't have enough reputation to write as a comment, added this as a new answer.

You can add asc or desc to order by clause.

```
ORDER BY x_field='A' ASC, x_field='I' DESC, x_field='P' DESC, x_field='F' ASC
```

which makes I first, P second and A as last one and F before the last.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using MySQL 4.0 afterwards, consider using `FIELD()` . It returns the index position of the first argument through the next arguments and it is case-sensitive.

```
ORDER BY FIELD(x_field, 'f', 'p', 'i', 'a')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can order by a selected column or other expressions.

Here an example, how to order by the result of a case-statement:

```sql
  SELECT col1
       , col2
    FROM tbl_Bill
   WHERE col1 = 0
ORDER BY -- order by case-statement
    CASE WHEN tbl_Bill.IsGen = 0 THEN 0
         WHEN tbl_Bill.IsGen = 1 THEN 1
         ELSE 2 END
```

The result will be a List starting with "IsGen = 0" rows, followed by "IsGen = 1" rows and all other rows a the end.

You could add more order-parameters at the end:

```sql
  SELECT col1
       , col2
    FROM tbl_Bill
   WHERE col1 = 0
ORDER BY -- order by case-statement
    CASE WHEN tbl_Bill.IsGen = 0 THEN 0
         WHEN tbl_Bill.IsGen = 1 THEN 1
         ELSE 2 END,
         col1,
         col2
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -2):

you can use position(text in text) in order by for ordering the sequence