# SQL ORDER BY (sequence)

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I have a sql statement which I would want to `ORDER BY` a specific sequence.

`SELECT * FROM UserDB ORDER BY [Role]`

How can I make it such that the data brought to my `GridView` table is listed from Admin on the top, follow by User and Guests?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So you want to order by `Admin/User/Guest`?

Try something like :

```
SELECT * 
FROM UserDB 
ORDER BY
  CASE Role WHEN 'Admin' THEN 0 
            WHEN 'User' THEN 1
            WHEN 'Guest' THEN 2
  END
```

Does that work for you?

Another option would be to have (or add) a column `Sequence` to your `Role` table so you could define the sequence in the table itself  - and then just to an `ORDER BY Role.Sequence`.

Answer (score 3):

This is substantively identical to the question " [sql ORDER BY multiple values in specific order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332043/sql-order-by-multiple-values-in-specific-order) " and I strongly recommend you look at the solutions presented there.

Comment: The only other suggestion I would have is that if you're joining to a "Role" table, then add an "order" or similarly named field, join to the role table, then order by that field instead.  That would allow you to specify the order at runtime as well, which is my preferred way of doing things.