# Return results based on a custom order

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do a simple search based on ID's

```
SELECT * FROM `test` AS a
WHERE a.bla != '1' AND (
   a.id = 85355 OR
   a.id = 85353 OR
   a.id = 80090 OR
   a.id = 1 OR
   a.id = 300
)
LIMIT 0, 5
```

The issue is that the results are not listed according to my query.

I want the row order to be like this `85355, 85353, 80090, 1, 300`

I tried the following query but doesn't work.

```
SELECT * FROM `test` AS a WHERE a.bla!='1' AND (a.id=85355 OR a.id=85353 OR a.id=80090 OR a.id=1 OR a.id=300) 
ORDER BY IF (FIELD(id, "85355,85353,80090,1,300"), 0, id), FIELD(id, "85355,85353,80090,1,300")
```

Is there any way to sort the query results it according to my custom order?

Comment: This [page](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6332081/2145211) looks like your solution

Comment: Can you place the    show create statements  en show indexes of your table and some information about your data..  like if a.bla only contains '1' or '0' ?  and some example data on http://sqlfiddle.com/ would be nice if sqlfiddle is running again..

Comment: @RaymondNijland updated question and included the table schema

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `test` a
WHERE a.bla != '1' AND a.id in (85355, 85353, 80090, 1, 300)
ORDER BY FIELD(a.id, 85355, 85353, 80090, 1, 300)
```

For more information on the `FIELD` function check the [official documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_field).

Just to clarify, when you apply a function, a case statement or you use something other than the field itself in an `ORDER BY` clause you lose the ability to use the index (if any) on that field. Additionally, you're adding an extra calculation to be performed on the field, which also takes time to be performed. You will have to accept the fact that this will indeed result in a less performant query than one that uses `ORDER BY a.id`. However, it is clear that the latter will not fulfill the requirements of a custom sorting.

Anyway, as you are first filtering by a primary key with only 5 results you will at most match those 5 results. Ordering 5 results without using an index is trivial and should be 
resolved in a matter of milliseconds. Now, the more ids you add to the `IN` clause the more records you will have to order. If this number becomes `significative` then the query will begin to run slower. You will have to test based on your hardware and software configuration what `significative` means in your case.

PS: I've just realised that as `id` is most likely to be a primary key then you don't need the `LIMIT 5` as the ids in the `IN` clause are already limiting them.

Comment: @RaymondNijland do u have a better solution then? coz my table is pretty big. i have about 100k rows

Comment: @user2636556 no use mysql1 or PDO and prepared statements then you can stop first order sql injections but second order injections are still possible.. note mysql_* functions will be removed from PHP in the future..

Comment: @Mosty Mostacho well EXPLAIN to explain the execution.. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html ... but using an calculation / functions on the indexed field most likly makes it useless to be used for indexes.

Comment: @user2636556 I've just removed all the (my) comments as they seemed to be more confusing than what they help others. I've updated the answer with a summary of these comments. Please, remove your comments too. Thanks.