# How to return matched results in ActiveRecord and then remainder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, hstore

Say we have data like

```
< id: 1, name: "Bill", type: "Lemur" >
< id: 2, name: "Bob", type: "Cow" >
< id: 3, name: "Nancy", type: "Lemur" >
< id: 4, name: "Jack", type: "Seagull" >
< id: 5, name: "Jill", type: "Seagull" >
< id: 6, name: "Jake", type: "Cow" >
< id: 7, name: "Jess", type: "Lemur" >
< id: 8, name: "Nick", type: "Lemur" >
< id: 9, name: "Jacky", type: "Cow" >
< id: 10, name: "Jerry", type: "Cow" >
< id: 11, name: "Samuel", type: "Seagull" >
< id: 12, name: "Tessa", type: "Lemur" >
```

I want to return all results where type is Lemur first and then return the rest of the results in any order. I thought I could use the group method of ActiveRecord but I don't think I understood that correctly and it's doing something else. I've tried doing `Animal.order('Field(type, "Lemur")')` after seeing another Stack Overflow answer but that didn't work either. I need a relation returned as I'm going to pass this on to Kaminari to paginate. Anyone know how to do this?

To make things more complicated we actually want to do this on an hstore column but I wanted to figure out the general answer first.

This is on Rails 3.2 with Postgres 9.3.

Comment: You could select where type is equal to Lemur and then select where type is not equal to Lemur. Rejoin the resulting arrays.

Comment: @kobaltz Thanks, you reminded me that I need to specify that we want a relation back.

Comment: I hope this query help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/6332081/1297435

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Postgres doesn't have an "ORDER BY FIELD(some_column, 'Zebra', 'Hipo')" like MySQL does - you could try to use "Order by bang!", like such:

```
Animal.order("type!='Lemur', type!='Cow', type!='Seagull'")
```

As suggested on this post:

[Simulating MySQL's ORDER BY FIELD() in Postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309624/simulating-mysqls-order-by-field-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 2):

There is a SQL way to do it:

```
Animal.order("CASE animals.type WHEN 'Seagull' THEN 'a' ELSE 'z' END ASC, animals.name ASC")
```

This query puts all the animals of type 'Seagull' first, then order the rest based on the animal's name.

Thanks to the basic [switch case](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/functions-conditional.html) ;)

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you can do this via a GROUP BY clause.
All I can think of is this which may be a bit unelegant:

```
Lemur.all.concat Animal.all.reject{ | a | a.type == 'Lemur' }
```

Edit: That way only worked if you are fine with an array. Here's how you can do it with ActiveRecord::Relation (Rails 4 necessary for [where.not(condition)](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#not-conditions)).

```
Animal.where(type: 'Lemur') + Animal.where.not(type: 'Lemur')
```

Edit: Ooops, it seems the latter will also return an array.