# Fetch records in order of ids provided and those ids which are not provided should index after these in alphabetic order

Tags: mysql

I am stuck on a problem where i have certain ids which i need to indexed in first in result in order they are arranged (in array) and other records to be fetched alphabetically but to be displayed after them.

For example my sql query is mentioned below:

```
SELECT *
FROM `users` `t`
ORDER BY field( `t`.`id` , 3694181860160, 3690073978560, 3692021760768, 3696518283776, 3694455712256, 3698627050368, 3694698638592, 3696980086784, 3693461701760 )
```

It should bring the records in order (3694181860160, 3690073978560, 3692021760768, 3696518283776, 3694455712256, 3698627050368, 3694698638592, 3696980086784, 3693461701760) first and all rest of the records should displayed after these in alphabetic order.

Currently I am getting records from the mentioned list but in random order and rest of the records are not sure how they are ordered.

I have also tried to fetch results using

`order by find_in_set` but it didn't work either.

Please help.

Following is my table structure:

```
 `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `display_picture` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_login` datetime NOT NULL,
  `reg_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `user_type` enum('admin','user') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'user',
  `status` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `email_verified` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `feed_visibility` enum('public','relation','private') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'relation',
  `groups` text NOT NULL,
  `contact_allowance` enum('public','private','relation') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'public',
  `search_allowance` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `country` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dob` date NOT NULL,
  `gender` enum('male','female') DEFAULT NULL,
  `fb_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `street` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `is_admin` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `flame_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `device_id` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fav_cat` text,
  `credits` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `privacy_setting` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_deleted` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `reason_to_delete_account` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `verification_hash` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
```

Apart for the mentioned ids, I would like rest of the records sorted by their fname and lname if they are not empty.

I should also mention, Ids in brackets are fetched from another table.

I think I should also mention that I am trying to fetch user their rank wise. User rank is calculated and recorded in a separate table in Mongo db. While 'users' table keep the record of all users in MySql. 
It's hard to describe table structure of ranking. But we fetch user_id and rank field from ranking table.

I am fetching user ids , their ranking wise from ranking table and trying to fetch user information from users table inorder to display them in a page where all users are displayed their ranking wise. Among them few users haven't achieved ranking so their Ids are not in ranking table yet. I would like to sort them in their alphabetic order of their fname, lname (if they have fname, lname)

.........

I did re-think over it and only returning those records which are fetched by ranking table. So when more records are available in ranking table then the page will show more records.  I am using query as

```
    SELECT * FROM `users` `t` where `t`.`id` in (3694181860160, 3690073978560, 3692021760768, 3696518283776, 3694455712256, 3698627050368, 3694698638592, 3696980086784, 3693461701760 )
ORDER BY field( `t`.`id` , 3694181860160, 3690073978560, 3692021760768, 3696518283776, 3694455712256, 3698627050368, 3694698638592, 3696980086784, 3693461701760 ) ASC
```

It is working fine, and with time this will show more and more users.

Comment: Please provide the structure of the table. What is the other field you are trying to sort on?

Comment: Did you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332043/sql-order-by-multiple-values-in-specific-order

Comment: @Ali I link you mention is not useful for me since the values in bracket I mentioned is not static it will grow in numbers with time and keep changing as user's rank fluctuate.

Answer (score 0):

This, I think, should do the trick:

```
SELECT *
FROM `users` `t`
ORDER BY field( `t`.`id` , 3694181860160, 3690073978560, 3692021760768, 3696518283776, 3694455712256, 3698627050368, 3694698638592, 3696980086784, 3693461701760 ) DESC, `t`.`id` ASC;
```

If you need the specified ID's in the same order you put then in then you will have to select each one individually and union all the results together.

Comment: i am getting records in this manner. Posting result in short due to shortage of space.  This method is not working.`["3696980086784","3694698638592","3698627050368","3694455712256","3696518283776","3692021760768","3694181860160","3699651556928","3692701454400","3698600774656","3694185651456","3693845934656","3693594951616","3691028107200","3691373773376","3697095829184","3690766807168","3692501641984","3698855465792","3699391648768","3697583058176","3696726122496","3693843354368","3693046966528","3697718637760","3691835711424","3698454857408","3692364783936","3696155633984","3697502467584"]`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to re-think what you are trying to do with your query. The only way to guarantee order of returned records is to use and order-by clause, but it appears you do not have a field you can order-by in your table. From what I understand you want an arbitrary order on the returned values which is decided close to the time the query is fired and cannot be known in advance (i.e. is runtime).

So you have two choices:

- Add a numeric order-by field to the table, set values of the field to match the exact order you want data returned, then immediately query the table and order by the order-by field.
- Query the data then order the records yourself (outside the database) placing each item in the list exactly where you want it.

Answer (score 0):

You should have two level `ORDER BY`. First your sort by your preferred values and then by the rest. `9999` is just value that will be high enough to make sure that the non-preferred numbers will appear only after the preferred ones:

```
SELECT * FROM users t
ORDER BY if(@x:=FIND_IN_SET(t.id,'3694181860160, 3690073978560, 3692021760768, 3696518283776, 3694455712256, 3698627050368, 3694698638592, 3696980086784, 3693461701760'),@x,9999), fname, lname;
```

You may also rewrite this so that you don't need temporary variable:

```
SELECT * FROM users t
ORDER BY 
 IF(
  t.id IN (3694181860160, 3690073978560, 3692021760768, 3696518283776, 3694455712256, 3698627050368, 3694698638592, 3696980086784, 3693461701760), 
  FIND_IN_SET(t.id,'3694181860160, 3690073978560, 3692021760768, 3696518283776, 3694455712256, 3698627050368, 3694698638592, 3696980086784, 3693461701760'),
  9999), 
 fname, lname;
```

Downside in this case being that you need to provide list of preferred IDs twice.