# Sort active record object by cloth size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to sort active record object by cloth size but can't seem to generate a logic for it.

Clothing can of sizes: "S", "M", "L", "XL", "2XL", "3XL", "4XL", "5XL", "6XL"

I am getting the object by:

```
@by_price_levels = PriceLevel.select(:id, :level, :size, :price)
```

where sorting will be done on `size`. How can I sort by cloth size?

I have created an array of sizes for starter:

```
sort_order = ["S", "M", "L", "XL", "2XL", "3XL", "4XL", "5XL", "6XL"]
```

Comment: Are you using Postgresql?

Comment: yes i am using Postgresql

Comment: This can probably help you: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html   You can make a enum with the names for easy access and interpretation but then sorting by that field will be a cinch since it's actually an integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
@by_price_levels = PriceLevel.select(:id, :level, :size, :price).order(
  "CASE size
    WHEN 'S' THEN 1
    WHEN 'M' THEN 2
    WHEN 'L' THEN 3
    WHEN 'XL' THEN 4
    WHEN '2XL' THEN 5
    WHEN '3XL' THEN 6
    WHEN '4XL' THEN 7
    WHEN '5XL' THEN 8
    WHEN '6XL' THEN 9
    ELSE 10
   END, id"
)
```

Ref [sql ORDER BY multiple values in specific order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332043/sql-order-by-multiple-values-in-specific-order)

Comment: It works, but @obermillerk's answer suits better: we can easily add index to have fast sorting.

Comment: This is correct but slowest answer. And that answer is right and fastest. Fastest but not _flexible_. The middle and flexible option is to have `cloth_sizes` dictionary and have a `JOIN`. But it doesn't matter, because cloth sizes are always S < M < L ... So, *that* answer is 100% right and fastest (index by integer column).

Comment: Sorry, but me and @obermillerk gave you detailed description why Enum is right answer. Moreover, OP example `sort_order = ["S", "M", ...` shows us, that OP wanted PriceLevel sorted by size position. Moreover, when you considers `ORDER BY (CASE size WHEN 'S' THEN 1 ...` answer as right, you _automatically_ considers `size` as integer (as Enum does). When you text as simple as "it's 100% wrong". So, IMO, you didn't understand the question.

Comment: 1) You did "dictionary with JOIN" solution as I wrote above. 2) It's complex and DB specific. 3) You have no index (when you do, it would be complex functional DB specific index). 4) OP did NOT write he wants to sort Cloth as `..."5XL", "6XL", "S"]`, but he DID provide example `sort_order = ["S", "M", ...`. 5) Martin's answer either does NOT sort as `..."5XL", "6XL", "S"]`. So, conclusions: 1) You solution is right, but overpowered(too complex and not fastest). 2) Enum answer is still right.

Comment: 1) In real world we don't sort Cloth in 100 combinations, but do it in the 1 case asc/desc, provided by OP with `sort_order` array. 2) In real world we want to have simple and fast indexes (there is a good question, could you _ever_ create index for fast sort in your solution). The only one real _cons_ is less readability of integer columns vs string ones with size name.

Answer (score 3):

You can use active record [enums](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html):

That way, you can still assign the field by the string/symbol, but the underlying data will actually be an integer, so you can just use `order(:size)` to sort by size. Be aware when declaring the enum you should list the sizes in order, and adding a size anywhere but at the end could create data inconsistencies that would need to be handled.

Comment: Or you can define enum as hash and in that case order does not matter: `enum status: { active: 0, archived: 1 }`

Comment: The OP seems to want the sizes in increasing order, he just has an array for ordering since he was trying to figure out how to order strings differently from alphabetically (correct me if I'm wrong @Mohammad Ali). But for increasing order, this works and is cleaner than specifying an array that orders them. If you really want to order them differently then you can still do a more specific ordering, but this is cleaner for the general use case where you want sizes in a consistent order.

Comment: You can access the enum outside of the class and use that throughout the code base. The only way such a mapping is inconvenient is if you're looking at the db directly, which isn't something that you should really need to do if you're looking for size information, and if you really need look for size information, then you can deal with the mapping for the very few instances that this would be the case.