# SQL ORDER BY specific sequence with dynamic multiple values?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a table which have some material list. Now what I want is, I want to display some selected materials in a specific order. The sql query I'm running right now is:

`SELECT * FROM my_materials WHERE material_id IN ($materialIds)`

Where `material_id` is the primary key of the table and  `$materialdIds` is a variable that contains some dynamic values, lets say it has these values `1,5,2,3,9`

Now I want to display those materials exactly (1,5,2,3,9) in this order.

**Here is a similar question, but in this case the values are specific/static. But in my project the values are dynamic.**

[sql ORDER BY multiple values in specific order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332043/sql-order-by-multiple-values-in-specific-order)

How can I solve this with **dynamic values**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Field()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function:

```
SELECT * FROM my_materials 
WHERE material_id IN (1,5,2,3,9)
Order By Field(material_id, 1,5,2,3,9)
```

Instead of `1,5,2,3,9` you can specify `$materialIds`

Comment: It worked, It gets the values dynamically, thanks.