# Faster way to custom sort ActiveRecords without numerous queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The way my code is set up at the moment, it runs 5 queries based on my array, as shown below:

```
    sorted_issues = []
    ['Critical','High','Medium','Low','Informational'].each do |severity|
        sorted_issues << issues.where(severity: severity)
    end
```

Instead of having to run the `.where` method 5 times, is there a way that I can just simply run *one* sort command to sort it based on my array values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
severity = ['Critical','High','Medium','Low','Informational']
issues.where(severity: severity)
```

A `where` clause accepts an array and translates it correctly (as an `or`). It's listed under the `hash` example below (the hash key is `severity:` and the hash values is our severity array in the example above)

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where

You can couple this with a custom `order` clause to put them in the right order:

```
.order("
   CASE severity
      WHEN 'Critical' THEN 1
      WHEN 'High' THEN 2
      WHEN 'Medium' THEN 3
      WHEN 'Low' THEN 4
      ELSE 5
   END, created_at # created at isn't required but for illustration
")
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6332081/2892779

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand, sadly. Are you saying that I can do `issues.order(` followed by the custom order? Because I tried that and for some reason it's not liking the syntax of something here.

Comment: I got this to work, but I had to drop the "ORDER BY" inside the quotes since Rails is already issuing an ORDER BY with the `.order` method from what I understand.

Comment: @LewlSauce good catch, I should have dropped the `ORDER BY`. I updated the answer. Thanks for catching that