# Sort in non-alpabetical order in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, enums, group-by, sql-order-by

I'm automating a process at work where the output needs to be in a certain non-alphabetical order depending on a name (internal_product, type text) in addition to a number (type text). First I'm running a subquery where I collect information from four slightly different tables using joins. I then append the result with a `union` before the outer `group by` sums units and amounts. The pseudo-query is as follows:

```
select name, number, internal_product, sum(units), sum(amount) from (
 select fields, sum(x)
  from t1
  join join-conditions
  join join-conditions
  group by name, number, internal_product
 union

.....

 select fields, sum(x)
  from t5
  join join-conditions
  join join-conditions
  group by name, number, internal_product
) as foo
group by name, number, internal_product
order by number, name;
```

I tried to change a column in a helper table used in one of the joins to an `enum` type since it is used in the outer `group by` ([SO-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6333944/319826)) but the column type of course needs to be the same in the join-condition so the modified query was not valid. There are 30 product names so I would like to avoid using a `CASE name` as suggested by gbn and Guffa.

Are there other ways to apply a certain order in a `order by`?

Comment: You should give more information about the values you want to sort and how they should be sorted. Without any more information, a CASE statement is a general rule to sorting items by a specific value, but you could create a field that computes what the order should be based on your requirements and then sort on that.

Comment: I ended up using the CASE-WHEN.

Answer (score 1):

It might be overkill or complicated for your case, but you could create a custom collation in postgres to sort the way you want. Have a look at the documentation.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/collation.html

Comment: Thank you. This is certainly an option. :-)

Comment: You can only use an operating system or an ICU collation. I don't think that you can create a custom collation.

Comment: It was overkill so I ended up using a CASE-WHEN. But thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: ICU collations can be customized, but it's definitely not trivial.