# Select All the similar data in order wise

Tags: sql

I have a large amount of data in data base.Consider this i have a table of student records and i need to get all the student with A grade first and then the B grade and so on..

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a tag for the database you are using.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sql ORDER BY multiple values in specific order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332043/sql-order-by-multiple-values-in-specific-order)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want `order by`:

```
select t.*
from t
order by t.grade;
```