# How to sort table in ecto based on two columns

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have table with `time` and `operation` column. Operation column includes `create`, `update` and `delete` values and time has elixir utc datetime. I want to sort based on datetime and if multiple rows are present based on same time stamp I want to first take `delete` rows and than `create` and than `update`.

Wrong:

```
1. { time: TIME1, operation: "create" }
2. { time: TIME1, operation: "delete" }
3. { time: TIME1, operation: "update" }
```

Correct

```
1. { time: TIME1, operation: "delete" }
2. { time: TIME1, operation: "create" }
2. { time: TIME1, operation: "update" }
```

So it would always give priority to `delete` and than `create` would be selected and values related to `update` should come at last.

If we do it ecto using following query where it would always accept "delete" as first value but it would not sort `update` and `create` rows. I am curious to know if we could somehow extend usage of fragments in this query to have sorting based on all `create`, `update` and `delete` fields.

```
     |> order_by([e],
       asc: e.time,
       desc: e.operation == "delete"
      )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this (if you use postgres):

```
|> order_by([e],
  asc: e.time,
  asc: fragment("CASE ? WHEN 'delete' THEN 1 WHEN 'create' THEN 2 WHEN 'update' THEN 3 END", e.operation)
)
```

Details about such ordering here: [sql ORDER BY multiple values in specific order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332043/sql-order-by-multiple-values-in-specific-order)