# How to custom sort in spring java?

Tags: java, spring, sorting

I want to custom sort my list. My data table is **id and status**. I want to sort by status but not use asscending or descending.

I want to sort the order like this. The first is vacant cleant, then occupied, then booked, then vacant clean, last is out of order. So that the json display looks like this:

```
[
{
"status" : "Vacant Dirty"
},
  {
"status" : "Occupied"
},
  {
"status" : "Booked"
},
  {
"status" : "Vacant Clean"
},
  {
"status" : "Out Of Order"
}]
```

I use Pageable in my code. Like this. But not work

```
    Pageable paging = PageRequest.of(findRoomStatus.getPageNumber(), findRoomStatus.getLimit(), Sort.by("status" , "Vacant Dirty" , "Occupied", "Booked", "Vacant Clean", "Out Of Order"));
```

The question is, how to sort the data example b-a-c-d. Not ascending a-b-c-d. Not descending d-c-b-a either.

But custom b-a-c-d. Anyone have a solution?

Comment: I don't have a ready Spring Data solution but I'd try to map the strings to numbers you could order the elements by. Since you want sorting to happen at the database level you might want to do that mapping in the query (maybe in a convenient function). - Or keep a separate status "ordinal" column.

Comment: can add your answer in my post?

Comment: @Thomas, if you had to do the same with sql only, wouldn't you simply use order by? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332043/sql-order-by-multiple-values-in-specific-order

Comment: @dbl have a look at the accepted answer to the question you've posted. That's basically what I meant: map the strings to numbers and order by that number.

Comment: @Thomas I know what you ment and I know that sorting by single int field is much faster, still wondering why would one prefer it over build in mechanics that could result in the same behaviour.

Comment: And 15 mins later I'm still unable to find more elegant solution than the one that you suggested...Spring in this case is the bottleneck.

Comment: @dbl what built-in mechanism are refering to? The question you've linked states this `ORDER BY field, v1, v2, v3` is _pseudo code_ and if you have a look at the answers they're all suggesting some form of mapping (and those might not all be supported by all databases).

Comment: @Thomas I am refering to [this partiqular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6332084/2185630). It is a built in mechanic for sorting based on a custom ordering criteria. That particular answer is specific to `psql` and since I'm not an expert on it I can not say if it is the most optimal approach to this particular task and thats why I've asked "what if"... Depending on the underlying DB you could find different mechanics being more optimal than others. Now, when we speak of spring in general and we don't chase optimizations, the pattern with using ordinals is elegant and widely used.

Comment: @dbl I agree with looking for a general solution that would be supported by a wide range of databases. Just for completeness: the answer you're refering to is also some kind of mapping because it basically has 4 order by clauses which map the values to booleans (or numbers 0 and 1).

Comment: -dbl -Thomas thank you for your participation, I have found a solution to this problem

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could define your own comparator, since your sorting is so particular.